# Converting java jar file to .exe file without using external tools?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, exe

How to convert my java jar file into .exe file to use in all machines even if jre is not present without using any external tools ?

I need to expect my java file / jar files as exe files but i don't want to use launch4j or any other tools for some safety reasons.

Comment: [Its' doable, yes](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/111-making-native-installable-apps-with-java-9)